# Macbook 2,1 - Everything works except wireless!

Tags: 10.10, wireless, dual-boot, macbook

So I've been running Ubuntu through a VM for a while, and finally decided to run it natively through BootCamp, so I installed it, and the installation went fine.  As far as I can tell, everything works fine, except the wireless internet connection.  If I use an ethernet cord directly, it works fine.  If I try and connect wirelessly, it prompts me for the network password, then it does the scanning thing for about 30 seconds, and then the prompt comes back up.  If I enter the password, and then while it's scanning, I click the network, a box comes up that says "Wiress Network Disconnected", and then it resumes scanning.

The weird thing is, it has successfully connected before, but it's very sporadic (takes a while to connect, but stays connected), and I haven't been able to replicate settings that makes it connect.

Everything works fine in OSX.

Wireless settings:
SSID: linksys
Mode: Infrastructure
BSSID: 00:25:9C:45:5D:F6
Device Mac Address:
Cloned Mac Address:
MTU: automatic

Wireless Security
Security: WPA & WPA2 Personal (my router uses WPA Personal)

IPV4 Settings
Method: automatic (DHCP)
Everything is blank/unchecked

IPV6 Settings
Method: ignore

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you've moved on already, given the lateness of this reply, but I had similar problems with the Atheros drivers when installing Ubuntu 10.04 on my old Mac Mini.  Eventually, my only option was to plug a USB broadcom wireless in.

However, I understand that the Atheros drives have moved on significantly since then and it might be worth trying again.

If you're still wanting this resolved, please post into your question the results of running `lspci | grep -i net` which will confirm what kind of card you're running for wireless.

Troubleshooting the connection more generally, you could run a terminal window, then issue `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`, then watch that window as you try to connect wirelessly.  Again, post the results back into your answer so that we can analyse where things are falling down.

Comment: Haven't tried for a while, but thanks for the response! I'll give you the check for a helpful answer.